# Manage margins so that the last element(s) have no margin(s)

Tags: css, margin

I work with boxes and I want to always give the last element a "margin-bottom: 0". So first I give every element a "margin-bottom: 1em;". I now want to delete this margin bottom from the last element in my boxes but if there is an element within it doesn't work and I still have a margin at the bottom. any idea how to do this? It could be a paragraph or a DIV or SPAN or whatever, so I do not always want to do this by hand. I want to make a mixin wth this.

I tried:

```
section *+:last-child {
   margin-bottom: 0;
   border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

But in the last div there is a paragraph with margin so it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you'll need a class. There's not enough specitivity using last-child or last-of-type unless every section ending in a `<p>` tag or the same tag. You really should avoid the * as much as possible. It's a huge performance hit.

Comment: Hmm yes the more I think about it the more I think I need a class :-(.

Comment: there is also margin-trim, but for now (and a long time to come) for safari only... https://caniuse.com/?search=margin-trim

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want to use [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not). That is,

`section:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom:1em; }`

My syntax might be wrong for what you're doing but that's a start.

Comment: I think ":not" doesn't really help because I never know what kind of element the last one is, it could be a DIV or a P or a SPAN. But maybe this could lead to a soluteion … hmm.

Comment: @HenningFischer Then you can make it the last child of the parent element and it won't matter. Just <parent element>:not(:last-child). Again, I'm just winging it at the moment and not testing.

Comment: @HenningFischer just add a space. `section :not(:last-child)`

Comment: @abluejelly I think you might be right for his last comment.

Comment: When I do this in my pen it looks more like a mess ... .

Comment: @HenningFischer that's because you removed the margin from everything that was not the last child, which was kinda the inverse of what you wanted. Nix the `:not()` (like the other solution had) and you can _unset_ the margin instead of only setting the margin on things that are not the last child (like you tried to do with this)

Comment: Hmm, sweet, I think I understood, I think this works now.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally use class names for these and specifically target the class I want to modify. However, if you want to avoid class names, you can use last-child

```
Syntax:
:last-child

Usage:
p:last-child {
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

More info [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  section div:last-of-type p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: 3px solid blue;
 }
```

Seems to sort it.... However, this assumes the last element is a paragraph inside a div. If you have varying last elements, a class would be a much more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying some things on my own for the same kind of issue, here is what I did:

```
p:not(:first-child) {
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```

If you want to trigger every element inside a specific element (for me it was a class named ".hs_cos_wrapper_type_rich_text" — HubSpot), then you can just do this:

```
.hs_cos_wrapper_type_rich_text > *:not(:first-child) {
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```

This way the last element doesn't have bottom margin, the first doesn't have top margin and every element in the middle have top margin.

Cheers!